# NESTJS cannot get the value from the decorator using reflector

Tags: nestjs

I cant sort of get the value of the public decorator for public route that I defined. It always return an `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] TypeError`

```js
// auth.middleware.ts
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Reflector } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>('isPublic', req.route?.stack[0]?.method);
    console.log('isPublic:', isPublic);

    if (!isPublic) {
      // Implement your authentication logic here
      // For example, you can use JWT verification
      // and attach the user to the request: req.user = decodedUser;
    }

    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Reflector` class from NestJS, and the `Reflect` API itself, do not work based on strings alone. Just saying to get the `isPublic` metadata from the `GET` or `POST` or whatever method will not suffice, as you need a class reference (and optionally the method of the class) to get the attached metadata.

Instead of using a middleware, to make use of the `Reflector`, you should be using a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) so you can use the [`ExecutionContext`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context) to get the metadata via `this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>('isPublic', [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()])`, [like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata).

Comment: maybe this will be the approach that ill be doing, im done an auth guard but instead, i try to change it to middleware, however upon changing, I can't find a way to extract the value of the decorator.

Comment: Any reason you're wanting to use a middleware instead?